# preg_match in php with Space, Underscore, Dash and Dot

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to match a regular expression in PHP, using the following code.

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]*$/",$string)) { 
  // Show error
 }
```

I want to allow

- Integers (0-9)
- Characters (small letters and capital letters) (a to z and A to Z)
- Dots ( . )
- Underscore ( _ )
- Dash ( - )
- Space (  )

It does not work. Does anyone have any suggestions for what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[\w\s\.-]*$/",$string)) {
    #show error
}
```

It will also match empty string because of '*'.

Comment: this is a very dirty and poor solution, it allows anything, what's the point to use regex?

Answer (score 0):

You're practically there.

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_. ]*$/', $string) !== 1) {
  // Show error
}
```

Assuming you want to allow empty strings. Otherwise, change `*` to `+`.